# NextAuth gives error OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR invalid_client when authenticating with a custom provider

Tags: authentication, next.js, oauth, next-auth, app-router

I'm trying to use NextAuth to authenticate with a custom oauth2 provider ([Whoop](https://developer.whoop.com/api#section/Authentication)), but after the login completes on the whoop servers and I'm redirected back to my application, NextAuth throws the following error:

```
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error invalid_client (Client authentication failed (e.g., unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method)) {
  error: OPError: invalid_client (Client authentication failed (e.g., unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method))
      at processResponse (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/helpers/process_response.js:35:19)
      at Client.grant (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:1191:28)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async Client.oauthCallback (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:520:30)
      at async oAuthCallback (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js:120:22)
      at async Object.callback (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:18:83)
      at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:202:38)
      at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:49:30)
      at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:83:24)
      at async eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:242:37) {
    name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
    code: undefined
  },
  providerId: 'whoop',
  message: 'invalid_client (Client authentication failed (e.g., unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method))'
}
```

My config is as follows:

```
// /api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  //   debug: true,
  providers: [
    {
      id: "whoop",
      name: "Whoop",
      type: "oauth",
      token: "https://api.prod.whoop.com/oauth/oauth2/token",
      authorization: {
        url: "https://api.prod.whoop.com/oauth/oauth2/auth",
        params: {
          scope: "read:profile read:workout read:recovery",
        },
      },

      clientId: process.env.WHOOP_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.WHOOP_CLIENT_SECRET,
      userinfo: "https://api.prod.whoop.com/developer/v1/user/profile/basic",
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.user_id,
          first_name: profile.first_name,
          last_name: profile.last_name,
          email: profile.email,
        };
      },
    }
  ]
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I'm fairly certain that this isn't an issue with any of the variables present in the config. The clientID, secret, callback url, and scopes all work great with whoop. Additionally, the `profile` function doesn't seem to be causing issues - I've tried setting the values manually without accessing the `profile` argument and the error persists.

Any help on debugging this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I've been dealing with this issue for a week and finally found the root of the problem:

```
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error invalid_client (Client authentication failed (e.g., unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsup  error: OPError: invalid_client (Client authentication failed (e.g., unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method))
  at processResponse (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/openid-client@5.6.4/node_modules/openid-client/lib/helpers/process_response.js:37:19)
  at Client.grant (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/openid-client@5.6.4/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:1206:28)
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I went into the **process_response.js** file of **openid-client**, did some digging and console logging and found a hint to the error:

Lines 31-35 of **process_response.js**:

```
function processResponse(response, { statusCode = 200, body = true, bearer = false } = {}) {
  if (response.statusCode !== statusCode) {
    console.log("processResponse body raw - ",  response.body)

  if (bearer) {
  ...
```

console.log() output:

```
processResponse body raw -  {
  error: 'invalid_client',
  error_description: 'Client authentication failed (e.g., unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method)',
  error_hint: `The OAuth 2.0 Client supports client authentication method "client_secret_post", but method "client_secret_basic" was requested. You must configure thod" value to accept "client_secret_basic".`,
  status_code: 401
}
```

I then searched for the meaning of this and found the *client* option on the docs of next-auth [Client Option](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth#client-option).

From this I added the *client* option to the config with the flag like the hint says:

```
client: {
  token_endpoint_auth_method: "client_secret_post",
},
```

And then it worked first try.
Here is my config file and invocation in NextAuthOptions object:

**whoop.ts**

```
import { OAuthConfig } from "next-auth/providers";
import axios from "axios";
import { OAuthProviderOptions } from "@/types";

const callbackUrl = `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/auth/callback/whoop`;
const authorizationURL = `${process.env.WHOOP_API_HOSTNAME}/oauth/oauth2/auth`;
const tokenURL = `${process.env.WHOOP_API_HOSTNAME}/oauth/oauth2/token`;
const whoopProfileURL = `${process.env.WHOOP_API_HOSTNAME}/developer/v1/user/profile/basic`;

const WhoopProvider = (options: OAuthProviderOptions): OAuthConfig<any> => ({
...{
id: "whoop",
name: "Whoop",
type: "oauth",
version: "2.0",
client: {
  token_endpoint_auth_method: "client_secret_post",
},
authorization: {
  url: authorizationURL,
  params: {
    scope:
      "offline read:profile read:recovery read:cycles read:sleep read:workout read:body_measurement",
    redirect_uri: callbackUrl,
    response_type: "code",
  },
},
token: {
  url: tokenURL,
  params: {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    redirect_uri: callbackUrl,
  },
},
checks: ["pkce", "state"],
userinfo: {
  async request(context) {
    try {
      const { access_token, expires_at, refresh_token } = context.tokens;

      const options = {
        method: "GET",
        url: whoopProfileURL,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token,
          "Accept-Language": "en_US",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };

      const { data: user } = await axios(options);
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
},

profile: (profile) => {
  return {
    id: profile.user_id,
    name: `${profile.first_name} ${profile.last_name}`,
    email: profile.email,
  };
},
},
...options,
});

export default WhoopProvider;
```

**NextAuthOptions:**

```
import { prisma } from "@/lib/prisma";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import WhoopProvider from "@/lib/providers/whoop";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    WhoopProvider({
      clientId: process.env.WHOOP_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.WHOOP_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session({ session, token, user }) {
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was a dependency of `next-auth` - `openid-client`
Broken version `openid-client` for GoogleProvider: `5.6.3`
Upgraded to version: `5.6.4` and the problem was resolved.

Version `5.6.3` introduced a bug with a lot of providers as per `5.6.4` release. https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client/releases/tag/v5.6.4

I was using stock GoogleProvider and it was giving me this error

```
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error invalid_client (The OAuth client was not found.) {
  error: OPError: invalid_client (The OAuth client was not found.)
      at processResponse (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/helpers/process_response.js:34:19)
      at Client.grant (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:1206:28)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async Client.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:418:30)
      at async oAuthCallback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js:120:22)
      at async Object.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:18:79)
      at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:202:38)
      at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)
      at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:85:24)
      at async /Users/kirilldubovitskiy/projects/t3-example-auth-prisma/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63251 {
    name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
    code: undefined
  },
  providerId: 'google',
  message: 'invalid_client (The OAuth client was not found.)'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error today implementing GoogleProvider.

Despite openid-client being a next-auth dependency that should be added, it was not added by next-auth. After running an install of openid-client, it immediately worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).